# Difference between '(int)a ', 'a as int' and Convert.ToInt32(a) in C#

Tags: c#, variables, int

What is difference between the following cast/convert.

```
string a = 5;
int b = (int)a;
int  c = a as int;
int d = Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

Just curious to know about these different methods and where to use them accordingly.

Comment: How about reading the documentation?

Comment: Note also you can't use `as int` because it is not nullable, it has to be `as int?`.

Comment: I assume you read the documentation before asking this question. When you did that, you must also have read about the peculiarities of `(int)`, `as int` and `Convert.ToInt32()`. So our question to you: what was unclear about them?

Comment: All three mentioned explanations can be found in Jon Skeet's Awesome answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(int)a` is simply a cast to the Int32 type and requires `a` to be a numeric value (float, long, etc.)

`Convert.ToInt32(a)` will properly convert any data type to int - including `string`s - instead of just casting it to another type.

`a as int` is the same implicit conversion (casting) as `(int)a` therefore they both do roughly the same thing.

Points to note:

- `as` can only be used with nullable/reference types and `int` in non-nullable. use `int?` with `as`
- `(int)long` will return an exception while `long as int?` will return `null`

Comment: `string as int` *cannot* return null because the type it returns must be an `int`.

Comment: @Chris from MSDN: `The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception`

Comment: from actually trying that code: "The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type)" I assume that the docs say that somewhere too. To clarify this is because the return type of `myvar as T` is `T` and if T is int then it cannot return null because `int` is a value type that cannot ever be null.

Comment: @Chris my bad, didn't notice that! I normally use `(int)`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Just noticed also that you said "`(int)string` will return an exception" whereas I think its actually a compile time error...